# jQuery ready function is called twice

Tags: jquery

This is my html

```
<div id="projekt" style="position: relative; width: 90%;height:400px;"/>

 $("#projekt").ready(function() {

     .. do something with the div
 });
```

The problem is the ready function is called twice. What could be the reason ?

Comment: Can you show your HTML? There's a good chance you're adding this twice or perhaps even referencing jQuery more than once?

Comment: Could you possibly have two elements with `id='projekt'`?

Comment: Yes, I have jQuery referenced twice. But there is only one script element with jquery. When I remove this element, both jQuery referencies are gone. Strange.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's [a bug which can cause this](http://blog.jquery.com/2010/11/03/jquery-1-4-4-release-candidate-2-released/). Try updating or binding to the document instead of the div.

Comment: +1 - The 1.4.3 bug is the most likely cause, since the selector doesn't matter...you can do `$("#IDJFmliiojfasdfll").ready()` and it'll work :)

Comment: I tried updating to 1.4.4rc2 and the bug persisted. I'm using $(document).ready()...

Comment: Urgh, found what the problem was: my ready function was throwing an exception... which caused the ready handler not to register that the ready event had already been handled. See http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/7273

Comment: @nornagon - +1! That was the answer to my problem.

Answer (score 11):

If you include your javascript file twice, it'll be executed twice.  **This doesn't show up clearly in firebug**.  The `script` panel (where I went to debug the javascript problem) will only show the file once in the dropdown.  But if you look in the `html` or `net` panels you can see if there are multiples.

I had something like:

```
<script src="/scripts/project.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/scripts/project.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

(This is similar to @chs answer, but not specific to rails.)

Comment: This was the cause of my "ready" function firing twice.  I had included the js file once in the tiles-template "layout"... -And, had *again* included the same file via the tiles-definition "add-attribute".  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution to this problem.

You should use this code

```
$(document).bind("ready", MyDocumentReadyHandler)
```

instead of the code

```
$(document).ready(...);
```

You can read more about the "ready" function using this [url](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this happen when I have an alert('...'); somewhere inside the .ready callback.  This happens as recently as jQuery 1.5.2.  Taking the alert out makes the code only run once.

Answer (score 1):

No need to add application option at the following tag in config/application.rb
 config.action_view.javascript_expansions[:defaults] = %w(jquery application)

It will call applcation.js twice, so the functions also runs twice in your application

Answer (score 1):

if you have a wrong src in iframe like `<iframe src="../" ...></iframe>`, the function ready() will be executed twice. Make sure you have a valid URL.

Ex.:

```
<iframe src="../something.html" ... ></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way of invoking `ready()` is for `document`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    ...
});
```

Comment: $().ready(handler) is [equivalent](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) but not recommended. Why is it not recommended?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. It went away when I moved my JS to another file and included it in the head tag instead of below the div I was working on.

Answer (score 0):

You will run into the same issue when using `JQM(jQueryMobile)`, but the issue in my case was having duplicate `data-role="content"` attributes. That attribute triggers the processing of everything inside the particular div or element with that attribute. In my case a `.ready` function was wrapped twice with it and therefore executed twice. Hope that helps someone.